# Suprema BioMini FingerPrint programming in c#

Tags: c#, biometrics

I bought a Suprema BioMini Fingerprint device. It has a SDK, but the documentation is not that good, it just paste the code, without a fluidly explanation.

I´m programming it in c#, but I can not manage to get the Suprema library works, this is:

```
 using Suprema;
```

In the libs -of the installed folder- there is no a "Suprema" one.

I tried using c++, so, I pasted the line of the tutorial of the SDK documentation:

```
#include "UFDatabase.h"
```

And did´t work.

But there is only a UFDatabase.lib, which I putted in the Visual Studio Folder. It does not recognize it. If I do:

```
 #include "UFDatabase.h"
```

It recognize the line -of course, there is a file with that name-, but the functions does not work -maybe becuase does not match with the functions of the .h that is supposed to look at-

Some of you have some experience with this BioMini SDK, or any clue about the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: hi , I have the same problrm , have you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you resolved this and what version of SDK are you using, what do you want to achieve and from there I can be able to assist with this.

but you can do the following

copy the following to your bin directory

1. UFScanner.dll
   2.UFMatcher.dll
   3.UFDatabase.dll

Then add the following as refrences

1. Suprema.UFDatabase.dll
2. Suprema.UFScanner.dll
3. Suprema.UFMatcher.dll

you will need to copy this

UFLicense.dat to the same directory with the first dlls as well.

you can then follow the samples in the sdk and you will be able to proceed. I have used it in C# environment for so long not had a problem with it.

Comment: am having difficulty trying to convert the sdk code to pick enrolled user in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Change the version of your project from 64 bit to 32 bit in project properties page and also start project in the directory where the sample project existed it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [sdk download page](http://www.supremainc.com/eng/product/pc_22.php?mark=33) it has a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) wrapper DLL. You should be able to [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftcwa60a%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to that DLL in your [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) project and use the classes contained within.

Comment: Hello, I tried adding the references,  but I get: 

"....dll" could not be added.Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component

I already added the .dll using the "regsvr32". I added all, included the 64 bits ones.

I imported all the raw files to VS too, but not worked :/

Comment: In that case i'm not sure, as long as you're trying to add a reference to the DLL **for .net/C#**, not any other dll (for example one for C++) it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need a couple of dlls to run the suprema SDKs.In my case I was trying the biostation T2

1. `BSSDK.dll` This is the main dll with functions to search for suprema devices,connect,get user templates etc.
2. `libusb.dll` - This is to allow you tp connect the device via usb
3. `Libeay32.dll`
4. `ssleay.dll`

Make sure the dlls are in the folder where your app is running could be ../x86/bin/release.
Change app compatibility to run for x86 CPU in project properties.
create a class BSSDK.cs and paste the code given in the example C# app given.Remember to change it to match your apps namespace.